# IBM MobileFirst 7.0 - Http Adapter Invocation using trigger concept

Tags: android, triggers, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-geolocation

Can we call Http Adapters using triggers in IBM Mobilefirst.

I'm working on Location based Services and Push notification Integration part like when use enters into the Geofench area we need to call push adapter to send notification to mobile device.

Geofenche Code:

```
dwellArea: { // alert when we have stayed in the vicinity for 3 seconds
                        type: "DwellInside",
                        circle: {
                            longitude: pos.coords.longitude,
                            latitude: pos.coords.latitude,
                            radius: 50
                        },
                        dwellingTime: 3000,
                        callback: function() {
                            alert('Still in the vicinity');
```

Here Can we call Http Adapter invocation i.e push Adapter See Below:

```
                            WL.Client.transmitEvent({ event: 'dwell inside area'}, true);
                        }
                    }
```

Push Notification Code:

```
var invocationData = {adapter : "PushAdapter",
                                       procedure : "submitNotification",
                                       parameters : [ "Vinod", "Hello This is Push notification" ]
                                     };
                            var options = {
                                    onSuccess : onGetAccountsSuccess,
                                    onFailure : onGetAccountsFailed,
                                    timeout : 30000
                                };
                            WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, options);
```

can we directly call this push notification code directly in this call back in Geofench coding or is there any alternative solution for this.

Reference links:

Geo-fench:
https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/advanced-topics/location-services-hybrid-applications/

Pushnotification:
https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/notifications/push-notifications-hybrid-applications/#whatIsPushNotifications

Comment: There is API to call adapters, why not call the API when a geolocation trigger was called? Where is the question here?

Comment: I have updated question

Comment: I don't get it, why don't you just try and see what happens? Did you try? What happens? Are there any errors? is it failing?

Comment: It was not showing any error, but when I'm running this application on my android device. It is showing "Update available" and automatically updating the application and then nothing is happenning.

Comment: Okay, now you're talking about direct update?

Comment: I didn't write any direct update code in this. And also why the adapter is not calling and not getting push notifications. I tried in separate aplication their I can able to send notifications.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97280/discussion-between-vinod-kumar-marupu-and-idan-adar).

Answer (score 1):

I am not clear on the question... why not create something like

```
function sendNotification() {
   // your push code...
}
```

And instead of the `alert()` use `sendNotification();`?
Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1):

You do have different options here. If all you're going to do is transmit an event, then you don't need to declare a callback. You can just add an event to your trigger definition; for example:

```
      eventToTransmit: { 
         event: { 
            field1: "data1",
            field2: ["data2", "data3"]
         },
         transmitImmediately: true 
      }
```

Note that this will try to transmit the event (and any previously untransmitted events) immediately. If you had dynamic data, then you would need a callback and use the WL.Client.transmitEvent API, instead. In both cases, if there are communication issues, it will retry according to the [event transmission policy](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Client.html%23setEventTransmissionPolicy?lang=en). You would handle the event in your server-side adapter(s). Note that using events  allows you to separately update logic on the server-side without needing to update the client-side logic. You can also handle events from several different adapters without needing them to make calls to each other.

Alternatively, you could perform a call to invoke a procedure in an adapter. In that case, if there were any communication issues, you would need to declare a failure handler and implement any retry logic there.